# Duda en ManyToManyFields Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

soy nuevo en Django y apenas estoy aprendiendo varias cosas, digamos que tengo el modelo siguiente donde tengo las clases Persona, Coche y Préstamo, una persona en un préstamo puede seleccionar varios coches

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    DNI = = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Coche(models.Model):

    opciones_color = (
        ('p01','Azul'), 
        ('p02','Rojo'), 
        ('p03','Verde'), 
        ('p04','Negro'), 
        ('p05','Blanco'), 
        ('p06','Gris')
    )
    color = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices = opciones_color)
    placa = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=False, blank=False)
    matricula = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)

    def NombreCompleto(self):
        cadena = "Coche: {0} ---  Color: {1}"
        return cadena.format(self.placa, self.color)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.NombreCompleto()

class Prestamo(object):
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coche = models.ManyToManyField(Coche)
    fecha_pedido = models.DateField()
```

*obviamente Persona y Coche tendrían más campos pero para efectos de la pregunta no es necesario colocarlos*

mi pregunta es, cómo puedo hacer que si tengo digamos 2 personas registradas y 3 carros y la persona 1 alquila el carro 1 y el carro 2 entonces cuando la persona 2 vaya a alquilar solo le aparezca el carro 3 pues que solo le muestre el carro 3 a la hora de seleccionar.

Comment: Yo creo que es una pregunta bastante amplia porque habría varias formas de hacerlo, y no entraría en la parte de ayudarte con código, el cual no es el propósito de esta página. Pero para que te des una idea, en mi caso particular yo agregaría otra tabla en la cual consulte que carros están en préstamo activo, para así excluirlos de la  lista inicial donde la persona escoge carros. A grosso modo es lo que más puedo explicarte, lo siguiente es echarle cabeza como llevar eso a cabo, y empezar a codificar, buena suerte

Answer (score 0):

Primero obtener a lista de los pk de los coches que están en préstamo

```
pks_coches_prest = Prestamo.objects.all().values("coche__pk").distinct()
```

ahora obtenemos los coches excluyendo los que han sido préstados

```
 coches_disponibles = Coche.objects.all().exclude(pk__in=pks_coches_prestados)
```